# query_post order desc

Tags: categories, query-posts, posts

According to:http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

To show all posts in a category:

```
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'The Category Name', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
```

Works great, but if I want to show the posts

> ORDER BY ID DESC

Anyone have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use this to parameters `orderby` and `order`

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'category_name' => 'my_category_slug', 'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the param order can list via DESC and the param orderby sort by ID
for your example:

```
query_posts( 
   array ( 'category_name' => 'The Category Name', 
           'posts_per_page' => -1,
           'orderby' => 'ID',
           'order' => 'DESC'
   )
);
```

oder is only usable with ASC or DESC and orderby can use all fiels of the table posts.